# EXTJS Spreadsheet Model - Keep row number column, but hide actual row numbers

Tags: extjs

I can't seem to figure out how to do this and google has been no help. I am using the ExtJS Spreadsheet model. I am trying to show the column with the row numbers, but I want to remove/hide the actual row numbers. I only want to keep the column that contain the row numbers. Any ideas on how I might go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be easily done. As with every column, you have to add a custom renderer to the `rownumberer` column. So how do you get to that column?

For this, the `spreadsheet` selModel has a function `getNumbererColumnConfig` which you want to override. The unoverridden function from sources:

```
    getNumbererColumnConfig: function() {
        var me = this;

        return {
            xtype: 'rownumberer',
            width: me.rowNumbererHeaderWidth,
            editRenderer:  '&#160;',
            tdCls: me.rowNumbererTdCls,
            cls: me.rowNumbererHeaderCls,
            locked: me.hasLockedHeader
        };
    },
```

so, to override, you would do the following:

```
selModel: {
    type: 'spreadsheet',
    // Disables sorting by header click, though it will be still available via menu
    columnSelect: true,
    pruneRemoved: false,
    extensible: 'y',
    getNumbererColumnConfig: function() {
        var me = this;

        return {
            xtype: 'rownumberer',
            width: me.rowNumbererHeaderWidth,
            renderer:function() { return '&#160;'; },
            editRenderer:  '&#160;',
            tdCls: me.rowNumbererTdCls,
            cls: me.rowNumbererHeaderCls,
            locked: me.hasLockedHeader
        };
    }
},
```

[Tested in a Sencha fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1bjj)